# Eliminate fields with distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

i use distinct to eliminate duplicate fields.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  userId1, userId2, message, sentDate, ad1, avatar1, ad2, avatar2 
FROM 
(SELECT m.id, m.userId1, m.userId2, m.message, m.sentDate, m.readDate,
   u1.id id1, u1.ad ad1, u1.avatar avatar1, u2.id id2, u2.ad ad2, 
   u2.avatar avatar2 
 FROM (messages m inner join users u1 on m.userId1 = u1.id) 
 inner join users u2 on m.userId2 = u2.id
 where (userId1 = 8 or userId2 = 8) 
 order by sentDate desc
) as q
```

[image: response]

if one field equal to userId1 = 7 and userId2 = 8 don't take userId1 = 8 and userId2 = 7. How can i say this to sql?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation, please.

Comment: What do you do with the other row you want to "eliminate"? Simply ignore it? Which one to ignore: 7-8 or 8-7?

Comment: @TheImpaler yes simply ignore, thats the logic: order the fields by sentDate and which one is old than other, ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the techniques in [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1) to get the row with the highest `sentDate` in a group. Use

```
GROUP BY GREATEST(userid1, userid2), LEAST(userid1, userid2)
```

as the grouping.

Comment: this is a good idea but i can't change the fields value, otherwise data'll get wrong.

Comment: The two rows have different values in the other column. How do you decide which row to keep?

Comment: Order the fields by sentDate and which one is new than other, keep it.